# Using std::cout in DLL called from C#

Tags: c#, .net, c++, dll, console

My Windows app has a C# part and a C++ part. The C# app shows a console window when it's ran.

The C++ code is compiled into a DLL which is used from C# via P/Invoke.

The problem is that printing text from the C++ DLL via std::cout doesn't print anything. Printing from C# works fine.

I suspect C# has taken over the console, so C++ can't get a handle to it. The fix might be to get a console handle from C#, pass it over to C++, and use it to connect std::cout to the console window. But I don't know how to go about doing that.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** My C++ code is unmanaged.

Comment: In the C++, if you open a file (for writing) named "con", and then write to it, does it work?

Comment: @coder, @Gavin: The correct file name is "CONOUT$", see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`cout` is wired up by the C/C++ runtime when `main()` executes.  So if the C++ code is limited to the DLL, there probably is no `cout` to write to.  (This is an oversimplification but you get the idea.)

`Console.Out` is a `System.IO.TextWriter`.  If your C++ code is managed, you can pass that to your DLL and write to it.  But if you're calling it via P/Invoke I suspect that's not the case.  Maybe use a named pipe?

Comment: It's wired up when the C++ runtime library initializes, which does happen for DLLs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the C++ runtime isn't linked to the console correctly, because it's supposed to create it. There is a `std::sync_with_stdio` function that should correctly link `std::cout`.

Comment: Thanks, but sync_with_stdio (the static function in ios_base) didn't help.